# How to repeat one cell value X times in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a sheet like this

[image]

How can I loop on column `A` based on column `B` and create comma separated entries ending with `-0` , `-1` .... in column `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a UDF.

Press **Alt + F11** then right click in the `Project` column. Insert a new module and paste the code in module1.

```
Public Function textMul(ByVal target As String, ByVal n As Long) As String
    Dim tmpStr As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To n
        If tmpStr <> "" Then tmpStr = tmpStr & ", "
        tmpStr = tmpStr & target & "-" & i - 1
    Next i
    textMul = tmpStr
End Function
```

Then back to your worksheet, typing `textmul(A2,B2)` generates the result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lots newacc2240, it is what I was looking for